# unwanted column in entityframework database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I am working on an MVC project in Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and I have some unwanted columns in some of my tables and I cannot really understand why is it so.

In table `Categories` there is the column `Template_TemplateId` which is probably because in the `Template` entity class there is a `ICollection<Category>` property.

I want a `Template` to have many categories, however a one category can be repeatedly used by many `Templates` so I guess the `Template_TemplateId` column is something I don't want there.

Can someone explain, why is this so, and what should be a right approach to have the model the way I want it?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have Templates propert in Category class? That would make EF know you need N:M relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model First:**

Be default, EntityFramework creates **one-to-many** type relationships. When you create those, you need a foreign key in the "one" side of the relationship.

This is the "Template_TemplateID" field. It is the foreign key into the "Templates" category. However, you said you wanted a **many-to-many** relationship, so you are absolutely right; that field is useless!

You need to specify a cardinality of "*" on both ends of the relationship, then the model will create an *intermediate table* allowing the many-to-many relationship. The foreign key should go away at this point.

**Code First:**

Same problem, but the solution is to make a collection of "Template" in categories and and a collection of "Category" in templates, thus creating the many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a many-to-many relationship between Templates and Categories create two collections, on on each class - on Template, create a ICollection and on Category, create ICollection.